# How to use a regular expression in notepad++ to change a url

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need some help with our migrated site urls's. We moved our site from Joomla to Worpdress and IN our posts we have over 20K of internal links.

The structure of these links are like these:

```
www.mysite.nl/current-post-title/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=5259:related-post-title&catid=35:universum&Itemid=48
```

What we need is this:

```
www.mysite.nl/related-post-title
```

So basically we need to remove everyhing behind `www.mysite.nl/` up until the colon `:`, i.e. remove this: `current-post-title/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=5259:` (must remove the colon itself too)

And then remove everything behind the first ampersand (including the ampersand itself) until the end of the string, i.e. remove `&catid=35:universum&Itemid=48`

Of course only url strings containing this `index.php?option=com_content` must be changed.

I have dumped the table in plain text and opened it in Notepad++ to do a search and replace with regular expression because the content that must be removed from these lines is different every time.

Can someone please help me with the right regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go inside-out, rather than outside-in, replace `\/.+&id=\d+\:(.+?)&.+` with `/$1`. Also, paste a few into http://www.regexr.com/ and play around, although JavaScript and Notepad++ might have some differences in implemented Regex features, e.g. negative lookbehinds.

Answer (score 1):

In find what box enter below:

```
(www.mysite.nl)\/.*index.php\?option=com[^:]+:([^&]+)&.*
```

In replace with box enter:

```
\1/\2
```

Result

```
www.mysite.nl/related-post-title
```